# Is Funds Management available in OFBiz

Tags: ofbiz

Any one come across the "funds management module" or similar to that in ofbiz. I saw some tables are available for Budgeting but, I did not find any user interface for those tables.

Is there any module is suitable for the financial planning (Budgeting & Revenue/Expenses) requirement?

I am waiting for your valuable reply....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not fully implemented yet.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-3169

If you what to know it for sure you should as the mailing list. The developers used to be very active on the [mailing list](https://cwiki.apache.org/OFBADMIN/mailing-lists.html).

Comment: Thanks for immediate response... 
I will check that link.